# Can we access native things like contact list, camera pictures, etc of an android device in HTML5 and javascript using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I searched about how to access the contact list of android device in HTML5 and javascript using Phonegap, but did not get satisfactory results. Infact, the following link says;

"HTML5 doesn’t provide platform specific services e.g. getting a list of contacts or list of captured images from a phone, but HTML5 provides geolocation, if that has been implemented by the Web Engine.  For platform services you need a yet another 3rd party API."

http://zchydem.enume.net/2011/12/18/html5-for-mobile-app-development/

Am not clear whether we can access the native things.

Please give me your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: which phonegap version your working now ?

Comment: Am using Phonegap 2.9.0

Answer (score 1):

The blog post that you read is from late 2011. It is now mid-2014. Hence, that post is about 2.5 years old.

The roster of [supported device features in PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/about/feature/) can be found on the PhoneGap site.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Have a look at the documentation given on PHonegap site. [THis](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html) is for accessing contacts list. There are other SO posts as well